# Trigger of two tables in an audit

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, syntax-error

Good morning, I am trying to audit two tables, and I have investigated that it cannot be done, therefore I explain what I wanted to do:

1. I have two tables (Participante, Actividad) which are joined by a third table (Part_Actividad)
2. I want to audit the Participants table, but in the same way I need the Id of the activity to know in which activity the data of a participant is changed.

Ideas I had

1. Create a trigger like the following

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Tri_Auditoria
AFTER INSERT  ON Participante
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_Participante_ID Participante.Participante_ID%TYPE;
v_Actividad_ID Part_Actividad.Actividad_ID%TYPE;

```
BEGIN
   SELECT participante_ID INTO v_Participante_ID
        FROM Participante;

    SELECT Actividad_ID INTO v_Actividad_ID
        FROM Part_Actividad
        WHERE PartAct_ID = v_Participante_ID;

        INSERT INTO Auditoria(Auditoria_ID, Actividad_ID, Participante_ID, TipPart_ID_Ant, Part_P_Nombre_Ant, Part_P_Apell_Ant, Part_Cedula_Ant, Part_Genero_ant, Part_FNaci_Ant, Aud_Operacion, Usuario_Modificador, Fecha_Modificacion)
            VALUES (sec_Auditoria.nextval, v_Actividad_ID, :new.Participante_ID,:new.TipPart_ID,:new.Part_P_Nom,:new.Part_P_Apell,:new.Part_Cedula,:new.Part_Genero,:new.Part_FNaci,'I',USER,sysdate);

END Tri_Auditoria;
```

/
Result:
When I insert data into the participante table, it is not inserted and it sends a trigger error.

Answer (score 0):

Mutating table error, isn't it? That's because you're selecting from the same table which caused trigger to fire, and that's not allowed.

Anyway, you shouldn't do that because you have that value in disposal - just reference it using the `:new` pseudorecord, such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Tri_Auditoria 
  AFTER INSERT ON Participante 
  FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
  v_Actividad_ID Part_Actividad.Actividad_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT Actividad_ID 
     INTO v_Actividad_ID
     FROM Part_Actividad
     WHERE PartAct_ID = :new.participante_ID;        --> this

   INSERT INTO Auditoria
     (Auditoria_ID, Actividad_ID, Participante_ID, 
      TipPart_ID_Ant, Part_P_Nombre_Ant, Part_P_Apell_Ant, 
      Part_Cedula_Ant, Part_Genero_ant, Part_FNaci_Ant, 
      Aud_Operacion, Usuario_Modificador, Fecha_Modificacion)
   VALUES (sec_Auditoria.nextval, v_Actividad_ID, :new.Participante_ID,
           :new.TipPart_ID,:new.Part_P_Nom,:new.Part_P_Apell,
           :new.Part_Cedula,:new.Part_Genero,:new.Part_FNaci,
           'I',USER,sysdate);
END Tri_Auditoria;
/
```